# constructing an error bar with compositional data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem and hopefully  there is somebody to help me.

I have a data set with compositional data, for each weekday of 160 weeks the ratio of cars are measured. The sum of the three ratios sum up to 1. There are three types of cars in this research.

My task is to construct the mean and an 'error bar'. I used the following lines of code in R:

```
Day = rep(c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday",
"Saterday"),3)
cars = c(rep("nissan",7),rep("toyota",7),rep("bmw",7))
y <- colMeans(datadag,na.rm=TRUE)
delta <- apply(datadag,2,sd,na.rm=TRUE)
df=data.frame(Day,cars,y,delta)

p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=Day,y=y,group=Device,color=Device))+
geom_point() +  
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-delta,ymax=y+delta),width=.6)
print(p)
```

The code above give the following plot: 
[image]

The problem I face is that the error bounds exceeds the 0 and 1 which is not possible because of the compositional data. Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Aren't you suppose to calculate the standard error, rather than the standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is statistical, not to do with R. You are assuming that the standard deviation will "know" that your data cannot be negative. Consider the following.

```
foo <- c(0,0,1,1000)
mean(foo) - sd(foo)
[1] -249.5836
```

I am not sure if the same problem can arise with the standard error but I suspect it can...